# AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate) not working in AVAudioRecorder

Tags: ios

I want to record audio with `AVAudioRecorder`.

Here is the code:

```
-(void)recordButtonTouchDown {

    _textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05
                                              target:self
                                            selector:@selector(setVoiceImage)
                                            userInfo:nil
                                             repeats:YES];

}

-(void)setVoiceImage {

    currentCount += 0.05f;

    if (currentCount==50) {
       AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
    }
}
```

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate) not working, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possibly a floating point rounding error in the following statement, as testing if floating point numbers are equal really requires an [*Epsilon* value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon):

```
if (currentCount==50) {
```

Try this instead:

```
if (currentCount >= 50.0f) {
```

To confirm: add a breakpoint inside the `if` statement.